# Running JNI program

Tags: java-native-interface, runtime-error

I am running my first program in ubuntu.

But there was an error when I tried to run it:

```
 public class HelloWorld {
 public native String nativeHelloWorld();    

 static {
     System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");
 }

 public void print(){
 {
 String str = nativeHelloWorld();
 System.out.println(str);
 }  
 }


 public static void main(String[] args) {
     (new HelloWorld()).print();
      return;
 }
 }
```

this error was found :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:HelloWorld.nativeHelloWorld()Ljava/lang/String;
```

how can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

These lines taken from [Getting Stated JNI from SUN site](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/start.html)

> Make sure that the native library resides in one of the directories in
>   the native library path.  If you are running on a Solaris system, the
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable is used to  define  the native
>   library path. Make sure that it includes the name of the directory
>   that  contains the libHelloWorld.so file. If the libHelloWorld.so file
>   is in the current directory, you can issue the following two commands
>   in the standard shell (sh) or KornShell (ksh) to  set up  the
>   `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable properly:
>
> ```
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
> ```

Answer (score 0):

For Running JNI program in android, You should look at steps described [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/overview.html#samples), You will need to build the native code using this command

```
cd <ndk-root>/samples/hello-jni
<ndk_root>/ndk-build
```

After successful build you will get the .so file in this directory,

```
\hello-jni\libs\armeabilib\hello-jni.so
```

Assuming you are trying to execute HelloJNi sample program from SDK. Once you got that file in libs directory, Run the project using eclipse simple run button and you will have your HelloWorld :).